# Cleaning SQL Data

Tags: sql, t-sql

What is causing the two fields to be different ?  Is it a tab or something else ?  What is an easy way to clean it ?  I know I can somehow use replace, but I am unsure of what I am replacing and there are many more records with the same problem.

```
Name    Binary
MCMPAD  0x4D0043004D00500041004400200020
MCMPAD  0x4D0043004D00500041004400A00020


SELECT  Name , convert(binary(15), (Name))  Binary from VirtualTerminal
where Name  like '%MCMPAD%'
```

Answer (score 5):

One string ends with space-space `0x2020`, the other with linefeed-space `0x0A20`.  The difference is not visible when you display `Name` as a string.

The extra zeroes (space is `0x0020` instead of `0x20`) are for the Windows standard UCS-2 encoding.

Comment: To remove trailing spaces: `update VirtualTerminal set User = trim(User)`.  To remove linefeeds: `update VirtualTerminal set User = replace(User, char(10), '')`